# How to do Unpooling with caffe standard version

Tags: neural-network, caffe

I have seen users are using unpooling layer, which is mostly based on their own release of `Caffe`. For example this:

```
layer { type: "UnPooling"  bottom: "fc6-deconv"  bottom: "pool5_mask"  top: "unpool5"  name: "unpool5"
  unpooling_param {   unpool: MAX   kernel_size: 2    stride: 2   unpool_size: 14 }
}
```

In which `pool5_mask` is coming from this `Poooling` layer:

```
layer {
  bottom: "conv5_3"  top: "pool5" top: "pool5_mask"  name: "pool5"  type: "Pooling"
  pooling_param {    pool: MAX    kernel_size: 2    stride: 2  }
}
```

Is it possible to do `UnPooling` operation using `Caffe` standard version.? If yes, could you please show some examples? I looked into [layer catalog](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/tutorial/layers.html), however, I could not find unpooling operation. 
Your help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you see this https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/pull/2561

Comment: @orbit thanks for your comment. Could I ask how to define through `caffe.NetSpec()` function? and it is taking two bottoms, which function of caffe should I call for creating with layer object? thanks

Comment: did you solve the problem @S.EB? I have the same problem.

Comment: @Nima I installed caffe-unet it has deconvolution layer that is acting as an unpooling layer. I just saw a version of caffe, named [caffe-uppooling](https://github.com/mariolew/caffe-unpooling). You may compile either of them.